# Adding flow variable to Mule map payload

Tags: mule, transformer-model

What am I doing wrong here?  I want to set the payload of a Mule message to a map containing multiple values, one of them the contents of a flow variable.

```
<set-variable variableName="myVariable" value="foo"/>
<set-payload value="#[['STATUS':'OKAY','NEXT':'Test','TEXT':flowVars['myVariable']]]"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]"/>
```

The output of this is:

```
{STATUS=OKAY, NEXT=Test}
```

I was expecting:

```
{STATUS=OKAY, NEXT=Test, TEXT=foo}
```

I know I can do this with a series of expression transformers but, if I want to use this kind of notation, why isn't it pulling the value of the flow variable in?

**Edit: to remove typo in source code**  This solved the problem as noted by Ryan's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have unbalanced braces. There is an unnecessary brace after 'Test'.

Should be:

```
<set-payload value="#[['STATUS':'OKAY','NEXT':'Test','TEXT':flowVars['myVariable']]]"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I found that.  We cross-posted editing.  I'll accept your answer anyway.  Thanks.